# Print No Data Set Band for Empty Dataset

Tags: jasper-reports, dataset, no-data

I have a report which has a dataset. I want to print No Data Band whenever the query in the dataset returns 0 records (empty dataset).

I have set the "When No Data" to "No Data Section". But it doesn't seem to be working.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to print No data band whenever the query in the dataset returns 0 records(empty dataset) follow these steps:-

1. Go to **Report Inspector** and add **No Data** band in the report
2. Put static text, such as **No Data Found**
3. Right-click the report to open the report property section
4. Set **When No Data** property to **No Data Section**

After adding No data band whenever query will return 0 record "No Data" band will display the static text.

Comment: this seems to only apply to iReport ?

Answer (score 2):

For those like myself, who do not use JasperSoft or older iReport and
directly work with XML, do the following:

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports
   http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
              whenNoDataType="NoDataSection"
              name="freport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" 
              columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20"
              topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
```

Add `whenNoDataType="NoDataSection"` to the `<jasperReport>` element.

```
<noData>
    <band height="15">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="15"/>
            <box>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
            </box>
            <textElement />
            <text><![CDATA[The report has no data]]> </text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</noData>
```

Add `<noData>` element below the detail band.

Answer (score 1):

When I've tried the solution proposed by @Sharad I have found another way, in my approach no need to add **No Data** band:

1. Right-click the report to open the report property section
2. Set When No Data property to **All Sections, No Detail**

The final result will be the same report with no detail. In my case it responds to my needs perfectly.

PS: I used iReport 4.0.2